# Create a tablayout in an alert box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

In my application, I want to create an alert box with tab layouts.
Is it possible to create a tab Layout in a alert box??
Please help me out.Give a proper solution. 
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: I want to shows contents in multiple tabs in an alert box.

Comment: you can make Custom layout for it and inflate in your AlertDialog.

Comment: go for custom DialogBox

Comment: getTabHost() got error because I extended the Activity instead of TabActivity

Answer (score 1):

you can create a xml with table layout as like you want. Below there is an example of table layout from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff"> 
    <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp" android:text="Row 1"  android:layout_span="3"
            android:padding="18dip" android:background="#b0b0b0"
            android:textColor="#000"/>  
    </TableRow>  

    <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 2"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 3"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow> 

    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 3 column 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#b0b0b0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 3 column 2"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#a09f9f"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>  
    </TableRow>  

</TableLayout>
```

you can inflate this xml into your alert dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,     R.style.anyOfYourDialogTheme));
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
LayoutInflater mFactory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mView = mFactory.inflate(R.layout.CustomTableLayout, null);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(mView);
```

Please check it out and let me know the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom alert dialog.

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.YOURDIALOGTHEME));
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View alertView = factory.inflate(R.layout.mycustomtabinalert, null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(alertView);
```

mycustomtabinalert.xml is the layout file where you can create a tab layout.

Assign positive and negative buttons as required to your alert dialog

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
}
```

For creating Tabs, please refer article [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)